# Nginx redirects to default page

Tags: django, nginx

I am setting up a domain for my Django/Gunicorn/Nginx server. It works fine with IP address instead of domain name in server_name but when I add domain name it redirects to default Ubuntu Nginx page. My Nginx file looks like this (please note that I replaced my domain with example.com):

Path : /etc/nginx/sites-available/projectname

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}
    location /static/ {
    root /path/to/static/dir;
    }

    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock;
    }

}
```

I have run the command sudo nginx -t and sudo service nginx restart but no effect. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Do you really have `server_name example.com;` and `server_name www.example.com;` in your config?

Comment: @fvu No. I replaced my domain name with example.com to post here.

Comment: In that case it's wise to add that to the question, to avoid misguided responses.

Comment: @fvu You are right but I can't do that due to some reason. Does the domain name matter in this case?

Comment: na, just mention that you replaced your domain with example.com...

Comment: Are you sure your browser sends the proper `Host: example.com`  with the request headers? You can easily check that with the browser's developer functions (F12)

Comment: @fvu No, it sends www.example.com and not yorumsil.com.

Comment: @Jingo thanks for the edit.

Comment: Are your files in `sites-available` symlinked to `sites-enabled`? You can see what `nginx` sees with `nginx -T`.

Comment: @RichardSmith I did that when I first created the entry. I checked the entry in sites-enabled and it is same as the one in sites-available so that must be working ?

Answer (score 2):

1- see main nginx.conf how include all config files. if it is including site-enabled path then go to path and see is a shortcut to config file of this site under site available?

or if all sites are enabled in nginx config file include directly available

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
```

2-mix two server define code once and with rule forward non www to with www
3-if not work check dns config problem and see result from inside of server via putty not from outside of server with browser to see it is nginx problem or dns config problem.

note: changing dns name servers taken some hours to work and effect on clients.